# How to override bootstrap css in VS2015

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

Under wwwroot in the css folder I have created a new css file with just the following class (i'm just trying to change the colour of the navbar for a particular area, not the whole site).

```
.navbar-inverse .recruiter {
  background-color: #278e00;
  border-color: #196700;
}
```

I've minified the file and I've also added the file to the budleconfig.json file:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/recruiter.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/recruiter.css"
    ]
  }
```

in the _Layout file for the area that I want the navbar to override I have made a reference too the minified version as the last css file that is refernced and I've appended the recruiter class to my div tag. When I run the code the default bootstrap still seems to take precedence pressing F12 (Chrome) doesn't show my css file being referenced at all

Comment: Could be relevant to start from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: In Chrome check the _Network_ tab to make sure the browser is requesting your file. Then check spelling for filenames and CSS selectors. Then check the specificity of your CSS selector to make sure it is specific enough to override Bootstrap.